# Gensler star test: if 'all A* is B' TF 'all B is A*' is invalid; coincidence or general rule of thumb?

Tags: logic

Like the title asks, I wonder if the invalid conclusion would tend to work if the letters of the premise were simply flipped to draw the simple conclusion?

Trying to logically parse the statement: “Lie” means “false statement” (taken from Gensler's intro to Logic), for example, I would reason out that:

```
all L* is F
TF all F is L* (invalid)
```

Logically invalid seems of course right, since not all falsehoods are lies per se.

But then I guess if 'all L is F' were a valid conclusion/statement, then L=F and so there would only be either L or F and not really both?

Sorry for the n00ber question, but I am just getting a start in logical thinking and trying to determine when reading single statements if there is a way to test their validity without knowing the premises upon which they were based?

Comment: What? Can you clarify your notation and what you're trying to say? I can't make heads or tails of it other than to note that the converse of a statement need not have the same truth value as the original statement. That is, all X are Y does not imply all Y are X. Beyond that, I don't understand your question.

Comment: ps -- maybe this will help. http://www.harryhiker.com/lc/docs/star.htm

Comment: Even in the terms of the Gensler Test, you should still star F in the conclusion, since it is a **distributed** term.  And in fact you should not star L in the conclusion, since it is not.  This would leave you with no stars on the right hand side, which the Gensler test would suggest makes it invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Gensler's star test is a little confusing and in cases I can think of, unnecessary.

A very simple way to check for logical validity in a structure is to substitute other words or phrases into the structure. Basically, try and find an instance in which the premises would be true and the conclusion false.

```
So here is your logical structure (basically):
P: All A is B.
C: All B is A.
```

Can you think of a instance where the premise would be true and the conclusion false? I can:

```
P: All cats are mammals. (T)
C: All mammals are cats. (F)
```

In this example, the premise is true, but the conclusion is false. Our initial structure has just been proven invalid.

Answer (score 0):

No:

> I guess if 'all L is F' were a valid conclusion/statement, then L=F and so there would only be either L or F and not really both?

"All L is F" does not entail that L=F. Otherwise "all women are human" would entail that "woman=person" but that is not so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on the statement:

In standard formal logic, there are statements like *A IMPLIES A* that always evaluate as true (without knowing anything about the nature of "A", just based on structure), statements like *A AND NOT A* that always evaluate as false and contingent statements like *A OR B* that depend on what A and B are (or on what else has already been established).

Your statement is contingent.  You can select values that make it evaluate as true, but it is not a reliable general rule.

The most common way of establishing which of the three categories a statement falls in is as follows:  If the statement is self-contradictory, or can be simplified to yield a contradiction, it is "logically false".  If assuming that the statement is false leads to a contradiction, it is "logically true".  If neither yields a contradiction, the statement is contingent.